# Outlook API :DymanicMenu showing only Top 5 items

Tags: outlook-addin

I'm working with Outlook API dynamic menu control for my add-in. In my application I'm allowing users to add the paths from network drive and then add it dynamic menu control.
Every thing works as expected but the dynamic control always displays only 5 items at any point of time.
If there are more than 5 items in the control ,it displays only top 5.
Is there any size that we can set to display all the items .
I'm using Outlook 2010.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What code do you use for adding new items to the menu?

Typically you need to define the **getContent** callback in the Ribbon XML markup. For a dynamic menu, retrieves XML content that describes the menu. Gets an XML string that contains the contents of this dynamic menu. The **getContent** method must return XML similar to the following to populate the menu. For example:

```
<menu xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
 <button id="dynaButton" label="Button" 
   onAction="OnAction" imageMso="FoxPro"/>
 <toggleButton id="dynaToggleButton" label="Toggle Button" 
   onAction="OnToggleAction" image="logo.bmp"/>
 <menuSeparator id="div2"/>
 <dynamicMenu id="subMenu" label="Sub Menu" getContent="GetSubContent" />
</menu>
```

Read more about the Fluent UI in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338202%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338199%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa722523%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Also you may find the following articles helpful:

- [Chapter 11: Creating Dynamic Ribbon Customizations (1 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548010%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
- [Chapter 11: Creating Dynamic Ribbon Customizations (2 of 2)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548011%28v=office.12%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)